# How to test if mouse event exists in Opera browser?

Tags: javascript, opera

Checking for a **mouse event** with `!event`, works as expected in Chrome.

But in **Opera** *event* always tests the same whether it exists and returns `[object MouseEvent]` or not and returns `undefined`. What's the deal?

```
!event //true
event==undefined //true
event==false //false
```

Comment: Have you tried using `event === undefined`?

Comment: What is `event`, where did you initialize it? Or are you really looking for the global `event` property which is just a IE legacy/compatibility workaround?